# Angular UI-Router: display a view when form is submitted

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have a plunker at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jBMecFACGBP8QgGpE0Jc?p=info) , which includes a form on the left. When the form is submitted, I wish to display the results as a `ui-view` on the right column. I use the `ui-router` to do this in the `vm.search()` function associated to the search button:

```
$state.href('/results');
```

however, the results page does not get loaded when the form is submitted. Could someone point me to the right direction for research or give me some quick hints/answers? I appreciate it

Comment: Don't you check console error log? you forgot to add $state to the controller function, so you get an error 'href of undefined is not a function' - $state is undefined

Comment: thanks, now I have just added $state in the controller function, but still does not work.

Comment: Add the new plunker please

Comment: yes, just updated the link in my post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the href usage, if you use go it works:

```
$state.go('formResult'); //display the results page
```

## $state.href -

> A url generation method that returns the compiled url for the given
>   state populated with the given params.

Example:

```
$state.href("about.person", { person: "bob" }) == "/about/bob"
```